# Passing an options/arguments file to Maven compiler plugin

Tags: java, maven

The `javac` command can be configured with a file by specifying that file on the command line with `@`:

```
javac @compileargs
```

I want to use that syntax in Maven so I can collect parts of the command line arguments in such a file instead of Maven's `pom.xml`.

The Maven compiler plugin [does not seem to have](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) a specific tag for that, so I tried [`compilerArgs`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>@compile-args</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <fork>true</fork>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But then `javac` complains:

```
javac: invalid flag: @compile-args
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

If I get the actual command Maven is executing (with `-X`) and call that myself it works, though.

I recently had a similar problem with [spaces in compiler options](https://github.com/CodeFX-org/mvn-java-9#-compiler-arguments-) so I assume a similar process is screwing with me here.

Comment: Did you try [compilerArgument](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgument) instead? They probably use the @ syntax already internally to create a temporary argument file from the `<arg>` tags, so your `@compile-args` would end up as an option in that file

Comment: What kind of problem is this why you like to have the arguments in an external file and not in the pom file? Furthermore using arguments should be done by using [compilerArgs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs)

Comment: @AndreasFester: You made me hope but `compilerArgument` results in the same behavior. 
@khmarbaise: I want to collect module system escape hatches like `--add-modules` in option files so they can be reused to launch the application instead of having to keep `pom` and launch script in sync.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Background info: The maven-compiler depends on the [plexus compiler](https://github.com/Tunaki/plexus-compiler).

If the build process gets forked it will take all specified arguments and create a temporary config file on its own (see [the code](https://github.com/Tunaki/plexus-compiler/blob/6bbf966416218fb32b81c09f66fb65d4ef2f4c79/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-javac/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/javac/JavacCompiler.java#L454)). The argument file will also include the user defined argument file, but the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html#BHCJEIBB) points out that:

> Use of the at sign (@) to recursively interpret files is not supported.

This means referencing an options file from Maven is not possible.